# PyQgis difference iteration

Tags: pyqgis, iteration, differences

I use Qgis. I have two layers that are two circles with the same center. One larger and one smaller. I want to do the difference between the two circles BUT only if they have the same "objectid" (the same id). So I have written this code: 
[image: Layers]

```py
for features in itertools.product(elayer.getFeatures("objectid"), player.getFeatures("objectid")):
    id = tuple(feat.attributes()[0] for feat in features)
    print("elayer" ,id[0] , "player", id[1])
    if id[0] == id[1]:
        pass
        processing.runAndLoadResults("native:difference",
        {'INPUT':elayer(id[0]), 'OVERLAY': player(id[1]), 'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
```

where elayer and player are clearly the two layers. But this code makes me all differences between all geometries in the two layers. How can I adjust it in order to get what I want?

Answer (score 3):

When you find a matching ID between two features, you can select them and then make use of the [QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition.html) which allows you to use selected features inside your processing algorithm.

You could try something like the following:

```py
for features in itertools.product(elayer.getFeatures("objectid"), player.getFeatures("objectid")):
    id = tuple(feat.attributes()[0] for feat in features)
    print("elayer" ,id[0] , "player", id[1])
    if id[0] == id[1]:
        pass
        elayer.selectByExpression('\"objectid\" = ' + str(id[0]), QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
        player.selectByExpression('\"objectid\" = ' + str(id[1]), QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
        processing.runAndLoadResults("native:difference",
        {'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(elayer.id(), True), 
        'OVERLAY': QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(player.id(), True), 
        'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer. You would join the two layers on their `objectid` and compute the difference between the matching geometries.

go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Feel free to add more fields from either layer.

```sql
SELECT st_difference(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry
FROM elayer a
  JOIN player b
     ON a.objectid = b.objectid
```

[image]

To illustrate it, the `elayer` is redish, `player` is blue and the virtual layer output is hatched. Note that the 4th polygon from `player`, which has a different `objectid` wasn't removed from the underlying polygon from `elayer`